# android google play in app billing error while subscription payment .. could not able to get purchase data

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am using in app purchase option in my application. After subscription completed , I could not able to get a Purchase data , data signeture and toen those things.But the payment was succeessfull for all the time. I release my apk in Beta testing account.
I was getting error like this:
IabResult: IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature (response: -1008:Unknown error)

Here's my relevant code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   billingHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}


handleActivityResult Method:

public boolean handleActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   IabResult result;
   if (requestCode != mRequestCode)
       return false;

   checkSetupDone("handleActivityResult");
   Log.d("handleactivity","strat");
   // end of async purchase operation
   flagEndAsync();

   if (data == null) {
       logError("Null data in IAB activity result.");
       result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_BAD_RESPONSE, "Null data in IAB result");
       if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
           mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
       }
       return true;
   }

   int responseCode = getResponseCodeFromIntent(data);
   String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra(RESPONSE_INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA);
   String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra(RESPONSE_INAPP_SIGNATURE);

   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && responseCode == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
       logDebug("Successful resultcode from purchase activity.");
       logDebug("Purchase data: " + purchaseData);
       logDebug("Data signature: " + dataSignature);
       logDebug("Extras: " + data.getExtras());

       if (purchaseData == null || dataSignature == null) {
           logError("BUG: either purchaseData or dataSignature is null.");
           logDebug("Extras: " + data.getExtras().toString());
           result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature");
           if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
               mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
           }
           return true;
       }

       Purchase purchase = null;
       try {
           purchase = new Purchase(purchaseData, dataSignature);
           String sku = purchase.getSku();

           // Verify signature
           if (!Security.verifyPurchase(mSignatureBase64, purchaseData, dataSignature)) {
               logError("Purchase signature verification FAILED for sku " + sku);
               result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_VERIFICATION_FAILED, "Signature verification failed for sku " + sku);
               if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
                   mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, purchase);
               }
               return true;
           }
           logDebug("Purchase signature successfully verified.");
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           logError("Failed to parse purchase data.");
           e.printStackTrace();
           result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_BAD_RESPONSE, "Failed to parse purchase data.");
           if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
               mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
           }
           return true;
       }

       if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
           mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK, "Success"), purchase);
       }
   }
   else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       // result code was OK, but in-app billing response was not OK.
       logDebug("Result code was OK but in-app billing response was not OK: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));
       if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
           result = new IabResult(responseCode, "Problem purchashing item.");
           mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
       }
   }
   else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
       logDebug("Purchase canceled - Response: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));
       result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_USER_CANCELLED, "User canceled.");
       if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
           mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
       }
   }
   else {
       logError("Purchase failed. Result code: " + Integer.toString(resultCode)
               + ". Response: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));
       result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_PURCHASE_RESPONSE, "Unknown purchase response.");
       if (mPurchaseListener != null) {
           mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Logcat output:

```
E/SIAPv3: In-app billing error: BUG: either purchaseData or dataSignature is null.
D/SIAPv3: Extras: Bundle[{RESPONSE_CODE=0}]
E/Michael: onIabPurchaseFinished
D/Onpurchasefinished: start
E/Michael: Try to print NULL object
E/Michael: IabResult: IAB returned null purchaseData or dataSignature (response: -1008:Unknown error)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Please go through the code via below URL

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bvan8Wd3Y-Hrhg-xUAjolOkgz2ue_0_W6B1yR9D7Sp8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience. im new to here..

Comment: Always include your code into your question (if its relevant) as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (which you obviously still didnt read). In addition you just posted 33 sites of code. Reduce the code to the problem itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information on that. Noone is going to read trough 33 pages of code.

Comment: Now i edit those things.Please check it now.

Comment: After payment successfull . it does not return INTENT_DATA API

Comment: I added the relevant pieces of code and the logfile to the post for your as you (whyever) still didnt.

Answer (score 0):

When a Subscription expires it no longer appears in the list of purchases.

See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) "The getPurchases() method does not return failed or expired subscriptions."

Comment: I cannot confirm that. For me, the subscriptions still show up after calling getPurchases();